# Java Synchronised List between Threads. Best practice

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a database logging engine when certain changes have happened. These changes get pushed to a queue in a thread that processes 25 LogObjects in the queue every 50ms.

I was thinking of using a Collections.synchronizedList() to hold the objects I still need to process in the thread.

The main application thread pushesses LogObjects into the list via `ThreadObjInstance.LogList.add(new LogObject("Something to log");` and in the thread I do `LogObject x = LogList.shift();` to process it.

However I feel like there might be better ways to do it or is this a perfectly acceptable approach? Or should I use ArrayBlockingQueue for his situation? Or another synchronised List Object... there are so many choices.

This is my first time working with threads so i'm trying to figure out what the best approach is for a job queue and which objects to use to maintain it.
Can I just add things directly to the threaded lists? Or do I need to use a synchronised method for that in the thread?

**The questions are basically:**

1. Where do I store a Synchronised List of Objects to process between two threads (In the processing thread or the main thread?)
2. What is the best practise to add/remove items from the list? via synchronised function or directly on the List object?
3. What are my choices for List objects when building a Job queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice mostly revolves around what you want to happen when the queue gets backed up for some reason and how much memory you want to use.

If you are comfortable halting your main process until the logging thread has cleared some of the queue then an [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) would be fine because it is bounded (and fixed in size) and will not eat your memory under high load.

If you are comfortable with ignoring memory issues when logging gets backed up (perhaps you are certain the logging thread will always keep up) then a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) may be a better fit as it is slightly more optimal and is unbounded. It can also be given a size limit but this is optional.

If you use either of these you do not need to add any synchronization logic as they do it all themselves.

> Where do I store a Synchronised List of Objects to process between two threads (In the processing thread or the main thread?)

Either - you would normally create it in your main thread and pass it to your logging thread and processing thread because they will both be sharing it.

> What is the best practice to add/remove items from the list? via synchronised function or directly on the List object?

[BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) provides a rich API of thread-safe adding and removal of items.

> What are my choices for List objects when building a Job queue?

See above.

Comment: Okay. Now there are options where it gets backlogged by 2000 items a tick(50ms) but those are short lived and should take up about 1mb(probaly exaggerated, morelikely to be 100kb or something) of ram that suddenly ticks up per tick, but then there are aeons where nothing happens and only 3-4 items are added per tick. But then it could be used in a busy enviroment where the load is 20 fold this. So I prefer a lowest possible profile. According to you I should choose LinkedBlockingQueue then?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets - Sounds to me like that would indeed be your best approach given that environment. The `LinkedBlockingQueue` will vanish to an almost zero footprint when empty. It may be worthwhile putting an upper limit on it of say 5000 and use `add` so you get an exception under exceptional situations or use `offer` if you are comfortable with losing log entries in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot afford to lose entries except in a critical system malfunction. The whole point of my application is that it offers an external detailed logging functionality so it can be logged who did what and changes can be rollbacked. 
like if there is a backlog of 100.000 I can always put out a critical warning message to the sysadmin because that shouldnt happen and I can always choose to gear up processing if there is enough tickspace in main thread left over to get rid of backlog. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets In that case you must block the processing if the going gets tough and your queue grows beyond a limit. It's either one or the other. (`BlockingQueue.put()` is the insertion method that blocks if queue is full.)

Comment: @biziclop - There are other strategies but things get a little complicated. He could use `offer` and send his emergency e-mail if it returns `false`. He could then switch to a backup queue and perhaps fire up some more processing threads.

Comment: I don't mind complicated code. In the case of backlog I'm going to make a config option where sysadmin can choose to lose entries to not interrupt main applicaton performance, or sacrifice performance to clear up the queue. I will notify him of the occurrance so he can take steps by increasing the processing per tick or increase the threshold before the backlog is too great. but for real, to create 500 entries within 1 second a lot needs to happen. Thats like large scale manipulation of items. usually it will be max 25/50 per second and then you still are busy.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes, there are many available strategies on the processing side. But from the main thread's perspective there are only two options, a slowdown (due to full-on blocking, throttling, or more processing threads taking more CPU) or lost messages. This is another good reason why the queue should "belong" to the processing thread, because all the potentially complex logic is on its side.

Answer (score 3):

1. Anywhere you want, where it's accessible by all the threads that use it.
2. `BlockingQueue` is made for this, and you don't need to do any synchronization yourself.
3. Numerous, but `BlockingQueue` is the most straightforward in this situation (producer-consumer).

Comment: So I add a BlockingQueue  to my thread object, do I add items to it via a synchronised function or directly on the queue? What would be best?

Comment: BlockingQueue is already synchronized. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the new threading api. The last time I worked with threads was 15 years ago... it was a whole different game back then... there are now so much options o_O

Answer (score 1):

1. In this case it seems like the queue belongs to the processing entity, that is the logging thread. But that's just a conceptual decision, at the end of the day they both have to hold a reference to a shared object of some sort.
2. It's definitely better to expose a single method for adding items (you really wouldn't want removing) than exposing the entire list, free for abuse. Again, that's got nothing to do with synchronisation, it's just the basic principle of encapsulation, or Law of Demeter if you prefer: only allow the clients to do as little as you can get away with. There's no reason why the main thread should know anything about how you implement the queue (or even that there is a queue), other than "I can put an event in here."
3. A queue is probably best represented by a `LinkedList` but since the queue is likely to be small anyway and the operation isn't on the critical path, the choice isn't likely to be important. Use whatever is easiest to read and understand. (I'd go with @Kayaman's suggestion of a `BlockingQueue`, as it takes a lot of work over from you and it's easy for anyone reading the code to work out what's going on there.)

Comment: The point is, the options can be small, but can become huge too in spurts. There can be points thwere there are 2000 items pushed within a second, and then great periods of nothing. the 25 is just to make sure the logging thread doesnt hog the cpu when it needs to process the 2000 alterations, but just keeps chugging along.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I see, that does change the picture slightly then. 2000 a second is still not too much in terms of memory but you want good insertion performance, which would probably tip things towards a linked list based solution.